# ruby on rails hello_app failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have installed ruby, etc. on RHEL7. I then did a "rails new hello_app". When I run "rails server", I get

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/abrt-0.1.0/lib/abrt.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- abrt/handler (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/abrt-0.1.0/lib/abrt.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/execjs-2.3.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:45:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/execjs-2.3.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
```

The github reference to execjs isn't very helpful. I have the RHEL7 js-1.8.5-17.el7.x86_64 installed as well as execjs (2.3.0). What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `nodejs`

```
yum -y install nodejs
```

On ubuntu

```
apt-get install nodejs
```